# How to hide a visualization depending on user in power BI?

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi

I am looking for a solution that allow me to hide a visualisation (graphic chart) base on the user that access the report.

Like RLS, I need to filter a visualisation, not only the data.

How can I achieved this?
Many thx!

Comment: This is not supported in Power Bi. You can't hide a visualization or page for an user. The only thing that is close is to filter data in order to have a blank table when a user is checking that page (with RLS).